# Ethernet not working 14.04

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet

I am new to ubuntu. My Ethernet is not working properly but wifi is working properly. For my ethernet to work, I always have to put this command after every restart(sudo ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 duplex full autoneg off).
Any suggestions?

The output of (lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2) is:

```
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:228d]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

Comment: This looks like a problem on the other end of the cable.

Comment: I think there should be no problem there. It works properly in my windows. Can we work out something for this? @Pilot6

Comment: The easiest way is to add this command to `/etc/rc.local` without sudo. And what is the network adapter? Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2`.

Comment: Ok I have added the output.@Pilot6

Comment: But still it looks weird that you have to limit speed to 100 and turn off autonegotiation.

Comment: No actually I searched for it on google and I had this command in some suggestions. Thus I tried it out. @Pilot6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like another revision of `RTL8111/8168/8411` controller. It may be not supported very well by the kernel `r8169` module.

If you did not upgrade the kernel to 4.2 yet, do it now. That will get a newer version of this module. It can be done by running

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
```

Reboot after that.

If the new kernel does not fix it, you can install another driver, that is more specific for this adapter. Run

```
sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms
```

and reboot again.

The `r8168-dkms` may not build for kernel 4.2, because maintainers did not update it for Ubuntu 14.04.4. In this case download and install this package:

http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/r8168/r8168-dkms_8.040.00-1_all.deb

Comment: I tried both of them, but a window popped up showing some software error. Even wifi has stopped working ubuntu now. What to do? @Pilot6

Comment: If you do not know what was the error, I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: In terminal, it displayed this:Building initial module for 4.2.0-30-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.2.0-30-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.037.00/build/make.log for more information.

Comment: Oh, I will update the answer.

Comment: Or you can boot with the previous kernel, if you have troubles with 4.2.

Comment: Now Ethernet is working perfectly fine after installing the package but wifi isn't working. How to fix this?

Comment: I suggest asking another question about wifi.

Answer (score 0):

driver version 37 is too old, use 41 instead:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r) linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
wget http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/r8168/r8168-dkms_8.041.00-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i r8168-dkms_8.041.00-1_all.deb
echo "blacklist r8169" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```